# Form with multiple submit option. PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a HTML form page with following code :

```
<form action="chainresult.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3145728"/>
      <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" size="30" />
      <input type="submit" value="GET SEQUENCE" />
</form>

<form action="helix_info.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3145728"/>
      <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" size="30" />
      <input type="submit" value="GET HELIX INFO" />
 </form>
```

My page has two browse options and two submit options which takes the use to 2 php pages. I want to have only one browse option with two options that takes the user to 2 different php pages based on what the user clicks.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly, but if you want to be able to post data to two different URLs, with two different submit-buttons, having two different forms is the only way to do it with plain HTML.

However, it would be possible to use JavaScript. In that case you could mash both forms together, evaluate the input before sending any information, and the post the data to different URLs depending on the input, using AJAX.

It is worth noting that going down the JavaScript-road, you would make the form unusable for anyone who has disable JavaScript.

I would probably suggest that you make it a single form, point it to an URL that can handle either case. So you always post the data to the same URL, and the server-side code would have to evaluate the input and decide what to do with it. That case you don't eliminate users that doesn't have JavaScript activated.

Comment: Que is i want two options that submits data to two different forms.

Comment: @gthmgeeky I am not sure I understand. What do you mean by options? Do you want to post two forms simultaneously, or do you want some input-element to be part of both forms, or how do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to combine the two forms into one (you don't even necessarily need the form tags), use JavaScript or jQuery to capture the submit button click, evaluate the input value based on your validation rules that route the form submission, and then post the values to a form, likely through ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit multiple forms but you will have to use Javascript. It should be doable with jQuery without too much sweat and tears. Something like...

```
$("#my-submit-button").click(function(){
   $("#first-form").submit();
   $("#second-form").submit();
})
```

Comment: That wouldn't work right? How can the browser manage two simultaneous form-posts? I believe you would have to do it AJAX-style.

Comment: It probably wouldn't like that (I didn't test it). I was just trying to suggest an option. See this: http://www.9lessons.info/2009/06/submit-multiple-forms-jquery-ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the question properly, but you could use jQuery to change the `action` attribute of your form, depending on what the user chooses. Something among the lines of:

```
<form id="myform" action="dummy.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3145728"/>
      <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" size="30" />
      <input type="radio" name="formtype" value="uploadscript1.php" /> Option 1<br>
      <input type="radio" name="formtype" value="uploadscript2.php" /> Option 2<br>
      <input type="submit" value="GET HELIX INFO" />
 </form>
```

And in jQuery:

```
$('input[name="formtype"]').change(function(){
    $('#myform').attr('action', $(this).attr('value'));
});
```

I am not sure about the jQuery part, but it should work ok. Try experimenting with that. :)

Using this approach you should be able to send **the same data** to two different forms.

Comment: Here in action="dummy.php" i need to execute different php scripts based on options selected by user.

Comment: That's what the jQuery snippet does. Switches the `action` parameter of the form with the `value` parameter of a selected radio button, or "option", like you call it.